# Proper way to access Database within Laravel 4 Package

Tags: php, database, laravel-4

I'm relatively new to Laravel, but I think I'm understanding it pretty well. `</unintentional-rhyme>`

I'm creating a base package for a project, and it needs to interact with a database (which has been set up and functioning - I did a lot of logic in Route closures and am refactoring it).

I had `DB::table('shops')->where(...`

but it gave me a `Class \xxx\xxx\DB not found` or whatnot; so I changed it to

`\DB::table('shops')->where(...` to fix the namespaces.

Is this the proper way to alleviate the issue **within a package**? I don't want to be causing some sort of issue that comes back to bite me down the road.

Thanks

Comment: I believe you have to put use DB; at the top

Comment: That seems to have worked @Adam - if you want to list that as an answer, I'll choose it once it allows me to :D

Comment: Awesome :) Just remember seeing it in a video years ago

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to declare it at the top like so

```
<?php

use DB;

class myClass {
    public function foo () {
        DB::insert('insert into users (id, name) values (?, ?)', array(1, 'Dayle'));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I feel like this should be better-documented. haha

Answer (score 1):

### If you are using this in controller, so this is the right way to access data

```
Shop::where('condition', 'value')->get();
```

check laravel doc http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent